# how to passing a javascript object used by webengine.executeScript()

Tags: javascript, webview, javafx

I'm a beginner of javafx.
this is my function of javascript in my html file

```js
function setMap(mapExtent) {
    if (mapExtent) {
        var args = mapExtent.split(",");
        if (args.length >= 4) {
            frx = parseFloat(args[0]);
            fry = parseFloat(args[1]);
            frzoom = parseInt(args[2]);
            frMapType = args[3];
            if (pMap) {
                pMap.SetMap(mapExtent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I know how to invoke it in C#, like this:

```js
        public void setMap(string sExtend)
        {
            object[] objArray = new object[1];
            objArray[0] = sExtend;
            try
            {
                this.Document.InvokeScript("setMap", objArray);
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

this javascript function need pass a parameter(a javascript object), but in the API document of JAVAFX8, the parameter of method webengine.executeScript(String script) is a String type only. 
How to use webengine.executeScript() invoke the setMap(string sExtend)

Answer (score 1):

Get the window object

```
JSObject jsObject = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
```

then try to call

```
jsObject.call("setMap", sExtend);
```

Comment: what is the  window object? if there has a JS function named "test()" without any parameter, I get window object and write the code like this jsObject.call("test", null);

Comment: @RanQilin, window is a global object described as the standard [JS Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window). By calling webEngine.executeScript("window") you get it as wrapped into JSObject. And if the setMap() function defined globally, you can invoke jsObject.call("setMap", sExtend);